# Performance impact of Json type in Postgres

Tags: json, postgresql

Currently, in our application, we are storing the JSON data as **Text** type in PostgreSQL. We are facing few performance impact because of this table. When we analyzed the issue, we found that few inserts and select are taking some time to finish.

Will changing the datatype to JSON, help in improving the performance?

Note: We are not making any query in the JSON data.

Comment: I dont think so, JSON type is better for json's because of indexers

Comment: @PiotrKowalski you mean, there wont be any big impact if I change that to JSON type?

Comment: Exactly :) it has impact if you are using JSON and all different queries

Comment: The JSON type constrains the data to the JSON format and you can apply the JSON functions directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, `json` and `text`are virtually the same thing, except that `json` is checked for valid JSON syntax.

Is the performance always bad? Then analyze the query to figure out why it is slow.

Is the performance only sometimes bad? That is harder. Investigate delay caused by locks and I/O overload during checkpoints.

Comment: The performance is bad only for some period and it comes back to normal. There are no locks in the table.

Comment: If performance gets bad for a while occasionally, that could be checkpoint spikes. Turn `log_checkpoints` on and see if checkpoints coincide with bad performance.

Comment: I haven't changed any check point configuration. Ideally, it should run every 5 minutes by default right? The performance goes bad at same interval of 1 hour.

Comment: See if you can find out what happens on the machine during the time of bad performance. How are CPU and I/O doing? Any processes running on the machine only at that time? Try [pgbadger](http://dalibo.github.io/pgbadger/) and find out if there is unusually much going on in the database at that time.